# How to update data on App running in background

Tags: android, background-process

Upon launching my application, a few web service calls are made to check for new data on our server. When I launch the applciation from scratch it works fine, but my app runs in the background until the user hits the back button a bunch of times, but I would still like our web service calls to be made whether he's launching a fresh instance or resuming an instance that was kept in the background.

Is there a method that's called when the applcition regains focus? (And only when it "regains" focus?)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page explains Android activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Activity's *onResume()* will be called every time the activity is brought to foreground but that happens also when launching it for the first time. If you are looking for a method that is called only when the focus regained, try *onRestart()*.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was trying to avoid something like onResume(), the name of the method would imply that the app should already be running in the background for it to be fired, but I guess not. I'll give on restart a try and see how it goes, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate out your code written in onCreate() and onResume() overridden Activity class methods.  Save your data on onPause and reload it on onResume.